# Python Reading and Writing to Files: write() vs writelines() performance

Tags: python, performance, file-io

I have a pretty contrived (albeit realistic) example with (to me) some unexpected results.

Basically I want to read a big file and write to another file all the lines that contain a specified string.

For instance:

String to Match:

```
12348:
```

File contents:

```
12348:12345
zxcv
xcvb
dfgh
tyu
12348:123456
```

Write to file:

```
12348:12345
12348:123456
```

I have implemented this in several ways:

**Method 1: write() line by line**

```
def compute_write():
    start = datetime.now()
    with open("read.txt") as fh:
        with open("write.txt", "wb") as fh2:
            for line in fh:
                if "12348:" in line:
                    fh2.write(line)
    end = datetime.now()
    elapsed = end - start
    print("compute_write {0}".format(elapsed))
```

**Method 2: writelines() with an array**

```
def compute_array():
    ret = []
    start = datetime.now()
    with open("read.txt") as fh:
        for line in fh:
            if "12348:" in line:
                ret.append(line)

    with open("write.txt", "wb") as fh2:
        fh2.writelines(ret)

    elapsed = datetime.now() - start
    print("compute_array {0}".format(elapsed))
```

**Method 3: writelines() with generator function**

```
def generator_fn(fh):
    for line in fh:
        if "12348:" in line:
            yield line

def compute_gen():
    start = datetime.now()
    with open("read.txt", "r") as fh:
        with open("write.txt", "wb") as fh2:
            fh2.writelines(generator_fn(fh))
    elapsed = datetime.now() - start
    print("compute_gen {0}".format(elapsed))
```

Now to make it super realistic I repeat each computation 20 times and calculate the total time it takes. Results: (read.txt is ~700MB and writes ~130MB to write.txt)

```
`compute_write()` --> 16.159134s
`compute_array()` --> 12.453268s
`compute_gen()`   --> 15.374717s
```

Basically why is the `compute_array()` ~25% faster than the other implementations? What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: It must be faster since less processing steps are needed there. Why are you so surprised that one method is somewhat faster than others. It happens all the time. If timing is important you use the fastest method.

Comment: Without your input data it's not repeatable for me, but what I'd do next is to use `python -m cProfile -o ./profiler_output ./[my-script].py` and then `./gprof2dot.py -f pstats ./profiler_output | dot -Tpng -o profile.png`. You need https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot and then http://www.graphviz.org for the `dot` command.

Comment: Intuitively I'd say the difference is in the I/O caching behaviour somewhere between OS and machine. Doing File read/write at the same time could lead to more cache misses compared to doing one after the other. Above profiling method would give you an idea on what the program is actually spending time on, it would be interesting to get a comparison between `writelines` and the file readline iterators. See also http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/buffer-cache.html.

Comment: Thanks @MichelMüller for the profile information it is very helpful. I have run the profiler and `compute_write` spends 35.33% of the time in `open` and 11.92% of the time in the file `write`. This is as opposed to `compute_array` which spends 2.33% time in `open` and 11.90% in `writelines` however it also spends 1.49% of the time in `append`. 

So if I am interpreting the results correctly it seems to be something going on with the nested open. Which could be potentially throwing of the caching?

Comment: That's... interesting. I had no idea that `open` could slow you down that much. "open" is only called 2x 20 times, right? Does the time used in `open` increase with file size? And then only for `compute_write` example? If so, there seems to be something else going wrong, maybe try on a diffferent OS as well.

Comment: Correct open is called 40 times. I doubled the reading (and therefore also writing) file size and the new ratios are: `compute_write` 42.36% in `open` and `compute_array` 4.64% in `open`. So definitely seems like there is a correlation there.... Also I am running ubuntu 16.0.4.

Comment: You can use "dis" module to find out about what your code does at low levels and why an implementation requires more resources than the other.